# UWP / MVVMlight : Replacing Obsolete ServiceLocator

Tags: c#, mvvm-light

I'm updating my apps and now I use MVVMLight 5.3.0
the viewmodellocator crash at the line

```
ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);
```

I read that ih the latest version of MVVMLight, the class servicelocartor is removed, And the Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation was gone ...

So, what can/must i do for makes work the app again? 
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

From the blog post introducing the standard library version of MVVMLight, remove the line of code below:

```
// OLD ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);
```

Whenever you use the ServiceLocator.Current use SimpleIoc.Default instead. For example

```
// OLD var nav = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<INavigationService>();
// NEW
var nav = SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<INavigationService>();
```

http://www.mvvmlight.net/std10

Comment: I have reopen to another page because my comment has been deleted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47520508/uwp-mvvmlight-replacing-obsolete-servicelocator-and-simpleioc-register

Answer (score 1):

Always I use MVVMLight in such a way, without setting locator provider for `ServiceLocator`. Typically, your view model locator should like this:

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    public ViewModelLocator()
    {
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataProvider, SQLiteDataProvider>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDialogService, DialogService>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register(GetNavigationService);
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MessageViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<SearchViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<SettingViewModel>();
        ...
    }

    public MainViewModel MainViewModel => SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<MainViewModel>(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    public MessageViewModel MessageViewModel => SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<MessageViewModel>(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    public SearchViewModel SearchViewModel => SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<SearchViewModel>(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    public SettingViewModel SettingViewModel => SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<SettingViewModel>(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    ...

    public INavigationService GetNavigationService()
    {
        var navigationService = new NavigationService();
        navigationService.Configure(Pages.MainView.ToString(), typeof(MainPage));
        navigationService.Configure(Pages.MessageView.ToString(), typeof(MessagePage));
        navigationService.Configure(Pages.SearchView.ToString(), typeof(SearchPage));
        navigationService.Configure(Pages.SettingView.ToString(), typeof(SettingPage));
        ...
        return navigationService;
    }
}
```